# Should related Backbone.js views have references to each other, or talk through events only?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, eventaggregator

I have an application that does CRUD for a `Collection` of `Models`.  There is a `DisplayView` for each model that is always visible.  There is also an `EditView` that is visible only when the associated `DisplayView` is clicked on.

The `DisplayView` and `EditView` appear inside of different parent views.  Right now I am using the "event aggregator" pattern to tell my application to render the `EditView` when a `DisplayView` is clicked.  Pattern described here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/

When one of my `DisplayView` is clicked it fires an event that the parent of the `EditViews` listens to.  When it receives this event it renders the appropriate `EditView`, based on the model for which the event was fired.

This works well for most of my application, but is particularly cumbersome when I want to have the `EditView` change position based on the absolute position of the related `DisplayView` in my application.  Rather than have the `DisplayView` directly control the position of the `EditView`, it triggers a "please reposition yourself to these coordinates" event.  Such direct communication doesn't feel like something that should be broadcast to the entire application.  I'm starting to wonder if for my case I should just have a reference to the appropriate `EditView` as a property of each `DisplayView` rather than decoupling them.

The problem, as I said, is that they are rendered inside of different parent views.  The `DisplayViews` get rendered in the `HeaderView` while the the `EditViews` get rendered in the `ContentView`.

How do others handle situations like this?  The `EditView` in some ways belongs to the `DisplayView`, but that does not match the way my application's DOM is structured.  Assuming I do create a direct link between each `EditView` and `DisplayView`, how would I handle show/hide of the `EditView`?  Would the `DisplayView` also need a reference to the `ContentView` container, which it would render explicitly with the appropriate `EditView` as a parameter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As much as you can, definitely avoid views holding references to parallel views (as oppose to parent / child views) and modifying each other, this can quickly turn into spaghetti and make your code much more fragile. Instead, the following patterns allow your different views to stay decoupled while still get the job done.

#### Global Notifications / events

This is the one you mentioned. It works but like you mentioned is less than elegant because it broadcast itself in the global scope unnecessarily

#### Binding / Observer Pattern

make an object named `editViewPosition` in your controller and expose methods to let the display view change the values of the editViewPosition. The `EditView` could then listen for and observe changes in the `editViewPosition` and update itself accordingly. The strength of this approach is that later you can have 5 different `EditViews` all observing the same property `editViewPosition` on your controller and update themselves accordingly, and there would be nothing you need to change in your `DisplayView` for that to happen.

#### Delegate pattern

Instead of directly hooking up the views and calling methods on each other, you can allow the display view to have a `delegate` property, which can be set by the controller to be the `edit` view. When the `DisplayView` wants its edit view updated, it will check if its delegate exists and implements a predefined function, if so, it will call the function. This approach is more coupled than the observer pattern but still allows a high degree of decoupling (and later for instance you can swap an entirely different view in there instead of your edit view and the program should still work.) Weakness of this approach is that you typically only have a single delegate, but it is more direct than any of the other patterns mentioned.

#### Manually maintaining a list of objects to notify

This is almost an extension to the delegate pattern. Basically you have an array of `EditView` like objects in your display view, and whenever needed, your display view will go through the array and call method on each of those objects. This array would again be populated by your controller.

### Conclusion

Personally, I'd most likely use the binding and observer pattern for your use case. In general, views that are parallel (no direct parent / child relationship) should not hold references to each other and should only communicate via a common controller / event / notification / other super-structure that they share.

Comment: I like these ideas very much.  This is exactly the kind of suggestion I was looking for.

Comment: Tony, could you provide some sample code of the Binding / Observer Pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There is another option, in addition to those enumerated by Tony, which is "bubbling up" an event that is triggered when the `DisplayView` is clicked to the closest common parent view of the `DisplayView` and `EditView`. With the event you pass the coordinates of the display view and the model it represents. Then the common parent directly calls a method on the `EditView` to reposition it and render the proper model. Thus no explicit references between parallel views, and no global variables.

Bubbling events up multiple view layers gets messy using backbone's built in `trigger` and `listenTo` methods, but the Backbone.Courier plugin makes it very straight forward:

https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.courier

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your application decoupled keep it that way. Introducing direct dependencies between views will make your application less maintainable and overall more frustrating to work with.

Events are the way to go here.